# Update same content in multiple posts at once?

Tags: php, shortcode, content

Is there anyway to update same data in multiple posts in WP?
For eg, my post 1 includes content 'abcabc' along with other content.
Same goes with my post 2 - includes content 'abcabc' along with other content.
Is there anyway to update 'abcabc' so that it will reflect in both posts?
Can we display 'abcabac' in post in a code to text form manner, so that whenever i update the code the text updates?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this. One way would be to use a plugin that lets you add a widget area to anywhere in the content of a post, then just update the widget content.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a perfect use case for the [WordPress shortcode API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API). 
Create a plugin with your own shortcode like `[abcabc]` and let it be replaced with whatever you want.

```
function wpse_251229_shortcode( $atts ) {
    return "Replacement text";
}
add_shortcode( 'abcabc', 'wpse_251229_shortcode' );
```